# What is the maximum version of PHP that cakephp version 1.3.7 will work with?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a moodle course that uses cake 1.3.7 that has started generating errors.

These are the three that come up:

> 1. Redefining already defined constructor for class Object in /home/eslwow87/public_html/cake/libs/object.php on line 54
> 2. Non-static method Configure::getInstance() should not be called statically in /home/eslwow87/public_html/cake/bootstrap.php on line 38
> 3. Non-static method CakeLog::handleError() should not be called statically in /home/eslwow87/public_html/cake/libs/cake_log.php on
>      line 290

I am guessing that these are caused by a mis-match between Cake and the version of PHP running on the server (5.3.29).  Is my guess correct?

Answer (score 1):

you can open the file `Config/core.php` and change the error_reporting to this:

```
Configure::write('Error', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleError',
    'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT,
    'trace' => true
));
```

Or alternatively upgrade to a newer 1.3.x version which would actually fix these errors instead of suppress them, but I'm not sure where you would download that from as their git archives for 1.3 are now empty.

This answer is a combination of me copying and pasting other answers from similar questions which had some of the same error(s) as you.

Comment: Skrilled, I don't see a core.php file anywhere in the cake directory.  Or is in in the PHP directory?

Comment: I believe in app/config directory there is file like this